# Angularjs, do something with an HTML element in ng-repeat after rendering UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I add a row to HTML table using AngularJS by clicking a "Add row" button simply by doing something like $scope.photos.push({}). The new row contains a file input field and I want to trigger the file dialog of the file input field after the new row has been rendered. Is that possible and how?

```
.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.photos = [];
  $scope.addPhoto = function(){
    $scope.photos.push({});
    document.getElementById("photo" + $scope.photos.length-1).click(); // this won't work because the element is not yet rendered.
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="photo in photos">
 <td> <input type="file" id="photo{{ $index }}"> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please include some code as well.

Comment: It is possible. Make sure the new row you generated and it's data is stored in DB.

Comment: Try this :- angular.element(document.querySelector('#id')).click();

Comment: Added a little code

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I don't see you call `$scope.$apply();` in your method to render stuff dynamically.

Comment: I mean after you pushed new photo to scope you need to recalculate the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Using $timeout as follows, it works:

```
.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.addPhoto = function(){
    $scope.photos.push({});
    $timeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("photo" + $scope.photos.length-1).click(); // this works now
    })
  }
});
```